# How to get the "This. Is. SKATEBOARDING" achievement?

Tags: achievements, tony-hawks-pro-skater-hd

I would like to get the "This. Is. SKATEBOARDING" achievement in Tony Hawk's Pro Skater HD (xbox360) but it requires that I win a match online.

The problem is that there is literally no one else active on the game anymore. Any help guys?

Comment: I suggest making an account at x360a.org and asking there for someone to help you. They have forums for most every game where people try and get achievements. Looking for friends isn't something this format of site is really suited to. :)

Comment: If you had a second copy of the game and a friend with an Xbox live account you could beat them.

Answer (score 2):

The achievement is awarded for winning an online game which requires at least two players. Since you state that there is literally nobody active is a problem we obviously cannot really solve for you.

However I highly doubt nobody is active. I can still find games for Civilization 1 or the original Quake. You just need to find a community or someone willing to log on for you.